# How to Download a file with Google File Picker API?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, google-api

I've been following this [Google File Picker tutorial](https://gist.github.com/Daniel15/5994054]) and I've gotten so far as to get the file picker showing and getting the URL, but I don't know how to download the file using JavaScript. If I can use VB.NET, then can someone point me in the right direction?

I've been able to download files with VB.NET from my own database, but I don't know how to get it with the Google API or with JavaScript.

All of the file picker code works, and I'm calling this from the onSelect of the FilePicker:

```
function downloadGDriveFile(file) {
   if (file.downloadUrl) {
      var accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', file.downloadUrl);  // use selfLink??
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
      xhr.onload = function () {
         var content = xhr.responseText;
      };
      xhr.onerror = function () {
         alert('Download failure.');
      };
      xhr.send();
   } else {
      alert('Unable to download file.');
   }
}
```

And when I click on the download URL I get this error:

```
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted is an issue with your account reaching it's max usage limit. Different issue than downloading the file. I don't have any knowledge on the google file picker api, but I'm going to assume this is in the browser.

You may have to specify `req.responseType = "arraybuffer"` because it could default to json.

I recommend using http://danml.com/download.html. Browser API does not expose the download modal for security reasons. The hack is to create an invisible `a` tag set the url to the blob of the body that you received and programmatically `click` the tag. The library provided does exactly that.

Comment: [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18585447/6084118) said that the usage error comes from not setting the Authorization header, which I think I did.

Comment: I just tried using http://danml.com/download.html but when I open the file I just get the Google Drive URL to the file and not the file itself. @Dowon Cha